# "Post your code" warning

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

I previously suggested the warning for users submitting a question with only one tag on it.

Following up on that, I'd like to suggest another (relatively unobtrusive) warning to new users that suggests that if they are asking a question about their code, that they provide a dang code sample.  How many wasted man-months happen every day due to people asking for help with their code and not showing it?

Maybe if it's the very first question they've ever asked, they could get a polite one-time Clippy™-style notice like "I see you're about to ask your first question.  Did you: 1) Check your spelling and grammar?  2) Provide a sample of your code if you're asking a coding related question?  First impressions are important!"

I know it's sort-of posted in the sidebar, but I think new users, no matter what the interface, always need some hand-holding.

Answer (score 4):

I think that warnings get ignored...  People will ask their question in a manor they think will generate an answer.  If code is required, they'll be told so.  If not, maybe someone will make a lucky guess...

Comment: The whole point is to reduce the flow of questions that actually require us to go in and tell them to post code.  It's such a waste of time for everyone involved.  Even reducing it by 25% would be huge.

Comment: Newbies dumping 1000+ lines of irrelevant code is just as annoying, I think this is sort of a no win situation.

Answer (score 2):

I really like your idea for if the it's the first question the user has asked prompting them with tips that are generally helpful for making good questions and receiving good answers. I wouldn't put a high priority on it, but if it's relatively simple to add to the system, I think it could be very helpful. But, I would definitely prefer it as a "first question asked only" kind of feature.