# Wondering: Are Some New Users Having Trouble Locating Their Questions after we Edit the Titles?

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

This just struck me as I was about to edit the title of a question from a new user: *I* would have no trouble finding this again - I know to go to my profile and look at my list of questions, then click the link.

But will a new user maybe just look in the Questions list? If so, he might not recognize the title I was about to change his to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that finding one's way to the profile display is not too high a bar for the site's intended audience.

I mean, this isn't your great-uncle we're talking about.

*My* great-uncle Fred, the Algol coder, is another matter, of course.

Comment: I don't think it would hurt if we had a prompt for new users when they write their first two or three questions, reminding them the title may change, and they should look for them under their profile, "Click the link saying "unknown(google)"". Only for the first few questions.

Comment: Similar in flavor to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/post-your-code-warning  ... I'm all for hand-holding for the first time someone asks a question.

Answer (score 1):

That may, in fact, be the case, but the value of being able to edit and improve questions for all (including the title) outweighs the inconvenience to any single user.  My guess is that it doesn't have much of impact since the message indicator will pop up when you have new answers/comments on your questions.

Comment: Yeah, except that's broken. Half the time it lights up and I click it, there are no responses.

Comment: And I wasn't suggesting we not change titles - I do that a lot (you say "C# <.net api>", I'll replace it with ".NET <.net API>"). I'm suggesting we ensure new users know about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think most people can find it in their "Questions" part of their user profile.  Many people have a minimal amount of asked questions and would not have any problem finding thier question again.  This would be a select few that would have an issue of this.  Combine that with the statistical occurance of radically changing question titles and we do not have too many affected users.

So it is a potential issue, but I always think back to the purpose of this site: Community Moderated.  It is a risk you take asking a question that could be modified by someone else.

Comment: Remember I'm talking about new users rep < 50. They may have just arrived from Google through a a search and have no idea what the site's about. They may not know that they _have_ a profile, or that "unknown(google)" has anything to do with them. Besides, I'm wondering, not saying we need to do something other than try to find out if it's true.